# Use slider to manipulate images?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, image-processing, image

Suppose that I have plotted many figures and have exported them as images. Now for the post-processing phase, I would like to import these figures and manipulate them in such a way that a slider assists me to view them together. The plots are produced by changing just one parameter. Thus I would like to put the name of this parameter on the slide as well as its range. Does anyone have experience for such manipulation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I will create some files to reproduce what you have

```
SetDirectory[$TemporaryDirectory];
SetDirectory@CreateDirectory["TestPictures"]; *)

Export[
   StringJoin[
    #[[2]]
    , ".png"
    ]
   , ImageResize[
    ExampleData[#]
    , 100
    ]
   ] & /@ Take[
  ExampleData["TestImage"]
  , 5
  ]
```

Now we can use the [`Slider`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slider.html) in [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html).

```
With[{picturefiles = FileNames["*.png"]},
 Manipulate[
  Column[
   {
    picturefiles[[k]],
    Import[picturefiles[[k]]]
    }
   ]
  , {{k,1,"Index"}, 1, Length[picturefiles], 1}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Without [`Slider`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slider.html) but [`SetterBar`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetterBar.html), in this case better.

```
With[{picturefiles = FileNames["*.png"]},
 Manipulate[
  Import[k]
  , {{k, picturefiles[[1]], "File"}, picturefiles, SetterBar, 
   Appearance -> "Vertical"}
  ]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to change the name of the slider and also show its range on the slider?